# Python - Creating a Phrase from a poem

Tags: python

Given a poem how would I construct a phrase using the following:

These numbers are coordinates, row and column from where the phrase will.
(1,1),(1,20),(3,60)

my question is does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you give us more information? What are these coordinates to? A word? A sentence? A letter? Would you construct your phrase out of each element given by the coordinate? And if so, do the coordinates reference a string which is your poem?

Comment: Have you attempted some code yet?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I'm gonna take a shot at your problem by speculating:

Let your poem be a text file such that it has a bunch of words and at the end an end of line character (which you write by just hitting enter). The file will look something like this:

```
This is a poem
with many lines
much much lines.
```

Now you save this file and create your python script on the same folder so that you can open it easily.

Your script will now do two things: first open the file with your poem and store it as a list of strings. This means we will consider each element in the array as a line in your poem (the first coordinate point), and each element is composed of words (the second element).

So in code your script looks like this:

```
lines = []

with open('poem.txt', 'r') as poem:
    for raw_line in poem:
        line = raw_line.strip()
        lines.append(line.split(" "))
```

If we print our lines array we get:

```
[['This', 'is', 'a', 'poem'], ['wtih', 'many', 'lines'], ['much', 'much', 'lines.']]
```

So to finish, your phrase making function could take in an array of coordinates and will bring the words from the lines array like so:

```
def phrases(coords, poem):
    '''Takes in an array of tuples with x and y coordinates where x is
    the line number and y is the word on that line. Also takes in the
    poem array'''
    phrase = ""
    for coordinate in coords:
        line = coordinate[0]
        word = coordinate[1]
        phrase += poem[line][word] + ", "

    # this is messy cause there's a lagging comma space at the end but
    # figure that out later.

    return phrase[:len(phrase)-2]
```

Which if we give it our poem and three coordinates that are in range will yield:

```
print phrases([(0,0), (1,2), (2,2)], poem)
```

Will yield a phrase:

```
This, lines, lines.
```

To summarize: store your poem as a list of lines and each line is composed of words. The coordinate system is (line,word). Hope this is what you had in mind.

Comment: thanks this looks exactly like what i have been meaning to accomplish all day. What about if I didn't want it in a function

Comment: just get rid of the first line and declare the coordinate array before it. that part should be easy.